DigitalOcean Kubernetes and deployment
I have a DO Kubernetes cluster with two nodes and a K8S load balancer, all created manually via their control panel.
I have a Gitlab CI that builds a docker image and pushes it to the DO Container Registry, which is connected with the cluster.
So my question is, how do I trigger a rollout on a new image push to the registry?
What I was expecting was that when I push a new image (only with the latest tag), a deployment rollout would automatically happen, but it doesn't. If I apply the deployment.yaml file below, I get a message that it's unchanged.
deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: api
    labels:
        app: api
spec:
    replicas: 2
    strategy:
        type: RollingUpdate
        rollingUpdate:
            maxSurge: 1
            maxUnavailable: 0
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: api
    template:
        metadata:
            name: api
            labels:
                app: api
        spec:
            containers:
                -   name: api
                    image: <image>
                    ports:
                        -   containerPort: 80
                            protocol: TCP
                            hostPort: 80


You can use https://keel.sh/ for that.
I also recommend yo avoid images with :latest tag.

Thanks for the answer but I'm not looking into adding another layer of tools to my toolset. I'd rather know how to do this myself.

If you want to do this yourself you update the deployment to point to your new image. Therefore it is important to have a unique tag for each image, for example derived from the git commit hash.
